# react-pdf gives TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithPromise') when cmapUrl option is set

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js, react-pdf, pdfjs-dist

I implemented pdf previewer with 'pdf-react'.

It displays pdf file with no problem when font is english font,
but problem occurs when I use other than English font.
(it loads the page with no text with the warning msg:
`cmapreaderfactory not initialized see the useworkerfetch parameter`)

So I followed wiki to add cmap option to document:
`<Document options={options} />;`
https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/blob/main/README.md

I tried vite and external CDN method, but both methods gave me

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithPromise')
```

error (and consequently bunch of other errors)

I researched web but could not find solution..

Does anyone have idea why this occur/ how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

hi bro，you need to cache options like this, it will work ok.

```
const opt = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      cMapUrl: '/bcmaps/',
      cMapPacked: true,
    };
  }, []);
...
return <Document {...props} options={opt}>
```